# How to let authors revise other authors drafts, but keep them from publishing?

Tags: admin, permissions, publish

I want to give all authors permission to **edit** other authors **drafts**, but not **publish** them. It seems like the only way to give authors access to drafts by other authors is to grant them 'edit_others_posts', but this capability also lets them publish the posts.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a plugin called [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) to enable certain permissions to different userlevels/groups, this should be able to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you could hook the publish event and check there if the current user is the author of the post to publish (that should be just a few lines of plug-in code). Should be a whole lot more lightweight then the other 2 suggestions - while doing exactly what you want.

Comment: might add the function soon, since the question has 4 upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

[Approval Workflow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/approval-workflow/) is meant to create a workflow process in WordPress. This plugin adds a box to the post edit screen when a user does not have publish permissions for that post type. It also allows you to set a WordPress role as the approvers. Note: this role must have publish permissions. The approvers get notified by email when someone has submitted something to the workflow. This works on WordPress Multisite too.