# Edit draft from other author

Tags: permissions, draft

I need that editors in my blog can read and edit drafts from other authors.

I've tried some access manager plugins:

1. [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)
2. [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/other_notes/)

But none of these helped me. I've also looked for similar questions like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61192/how-to-let-authors-revise-other-authors-drafts-but-keep-them-from-publishing) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107062/how-do-i-make-a-draft-post-accessible-to-everyone), but again, nothing found.

How can I do this? It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
Specifically, the following:

> Editor – somebody who can publish and manage posts including the posts
>   of other users.

An Editor is exactly that - someone who can edit what other people are doing.

Ensure that the Users who you want to have Editor rights are assigned as Editors in the Users menu.

If this doesn't answer the question, please revise your question with more information and perhaps this may also help understand a bit more: [Allow Editors to edit pending posts but not draft ones](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95174/allow-editors-to-edit-pending-posts-but-not-draft-ones)

Comment: Hi TomC, this is not the case. In my question I said that I would like that editors could edit drafts (private posts). Editors can only edit published posts from other authors. Thanks.

Comment: According to the link I've shown, it says that edit_private_posts is possible for Editors. Alternatively, you can look at adding capabilities to your Editors here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Comment: Hi TomC, you were right. I had an old plugin that was causing a conflict with the user roles. Sorry for this question and thanks for your patience.